# Horizon javascript causes 404 on client

Tags: horizon

I have a sitecore 9.3 setup with Horizon installed. On any given page, sitecore seems to inject the following script:

```
<script src='/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/HorizonCanvas/horizon.bundle.js'></script>
```

Right after the body tag. This script seems to be restricted, so it redirects to:

```
https://myhostname/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2Fsitecore%2Fshell%2Fclient%2FApplications%2FHorizonCanvas%2Fhorizon.bundle.js
```

And this triggers a 404. What is happening here? Why is this script being injected into all my pages?

Comment: The above script will inject in editing mode/horizon editing mode only, is it injecting in normal mode?

Comment: It is injecting on the front end of the site - when im not logged in to sitecore.